# jQuery: don't waiting till animation finish on multi clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make on click event don't wait till the current animation finish and just execute the last click.

example code http://jsfiddle.net/dJpNU/
** Try to click 7 to 10 times fast and see the animation going one after one slowly

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("div").animate({
    height:'+=20px',
    width:'+=20px'
  });
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use `stop` which stops the previous animation.

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("div").stop(true).animate({
    height:'+=20px',
    width:'+=20px'
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dJpNU/1/

http://api.jquery.com/stop/